# How to generate date in SQL Query?

Tags: sql, date, insert, dateadd

I want to generate date value since 1/1/2011 - 31/12/2011 on sql query.

Example 
My Table A

```
Field A     Field B       Field C
   1       01/01/2011      125
   2       03/01/2011      100
   3       05/01/2011       50
```

I want to result :

```
Field A     Field B       Field C
   1       01/01/2011      125
   0       02/01/2011        0
   2       03/01/2011      100
   0       04/01/2011        0
   3       05/01/2011       50 
   ...
   0       31/12/2011       0
```

Please Advice Me and Thank a lot.

Comment: you need a calendar table

Comment: Yes and Check Date in Another Table

Comment: What database server?  SQL Server/MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under SQL Server, you can create a table-valued function rather than creating a temporary table, as this is reusable between queries:

```
-- List all of the dates between startdate and enddate (inclusive)
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DatesBetween] (
    @startdate date,
    @enddate date
) RETURNS @ret TABLE (Date date) AS BEGIN

    DECLARE @dt date, @dtEnd date
    SELECT @dt = @startdate, @dtEnd = @enddate

    WHILE (@dt <= @dtEnd) BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @ret VALUES(@dt)
        SET @dt = DATEADD(day, 1, @dt)
    END 

    RETURN
END
```

This allows everything to be executed inside one query:

```
SELECT d.Date, COUNT(t.*) AS TotalOnDay
FROM dbo.DatesBetween('2011-01-01', '2011-12-31') d 
    LEFT JOIN MyTable t ON t.Date = d.Date
GROUP BY d.Date
```

Comment: You have just stolen my idea :) +1

Comment: Very good OOP, I will recommend you add index on the function for date, because there is JOIN CLUSTER...NONCLUSTER depends..., I had this problem when I have many rows The Index speed so much was incredible  RETURNS @ret TABLE (Date date  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ) AS BEGIN

Answer (score 0):

If your "Field B" is formatted as Date, you can use the function DATEDIFF(Day,StartDate,EndDate)
you can also change the "DATEDIFF(Day" to Year, Month or any other part you like.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In T-SQL you can write a query as:

```
CREATE TABLE #ALLDATE(Date1 date)
DECLARE @startDate DATE='1/1/2011'
DECLARE @endDate DATE='12/31/2011'

insert into #ALLDATE
SELECT [Date] = DATEADD(Day,Number,@startDate) 
FROM  master..spt_values 
WHERE Type='P'
AND DATEADD(day,Number,@startDate) <= @endDate

select * from #ALLDATE
```